# Что означает в С++ запись val = x ^ y; val &= val - 1?

Tags: c, c++

А именно `val = x ^ y;` и `val &= val - 1;`

```
__int64 dist = 0, val = x ^ y;

// Count the number of set bits
while(val)
{
    ++dist; 
    val &= val - 1;
}

return dist;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

^ - поразрядное исключающие ИЛИ (XOR)

```
a = 5; //   101   двоичное
b = 3; //   011   двоичное
c = ( a ^ b ); //   c   равно   110  двоичному  ( 6  десятичное)
```

&= - составное поразрядное логическое И. Как обычное И только с присваиванием.

UPDATE

```
val &= val - 1 // val = val & (val - 1)
val = 5 // 101
val = val & (val - 1) // 101 & 100 = 100
val = val & (val - 1) // 100 & 011 = 0
```

Продолжи таблицу дальше, улови закономерность и поймешь смысл

Написал бы еще как функция называется, может все вопросы отпали бы сами собой

Comment: можно по подробней как он работает

Comment: @good [XOR][1][AND][2]


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR
  [2]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AND

Answer (score 2):

[[@good](/users/7736/good)](/users/7736/good), конкретно про операции ^ и &= Вам рассказали, а в целом это подсчет *разных* разрядов в x и y.

val = x^y установит в val в единичку те разряды, которые разные в x и y.

в dist получим результат.

Answer (score 1):

Операции с битами.
^ - XOR - исключающее или, бит будет равен единице только если в одном числе он установлен в 1, а в другом в 0. & - AND - И, бит будет равен единице только если он установлен в 1 в двух числах. &= - AND с присваиванием.